# Is it possible to use a plugin for a Framework class?

Tags: magento2, plugin

I have written the plugin below but I can't seem to get it triggered.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ExtendedQuickSearch\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match;

class QuickSearch
{
    public function beforeGetMatchQuery(
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Helper\Mysql\Fulltext $subject,
        $columns, $expression, $mode = self::FULLTEXT_MODE_NATURAL
    )
    {
        var_dump('Plugin1 - beforeGetMatchQuery');die;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If the class you are intercepting is instantiated via Object manager then you should be able to interception.

Comment: I am pretty new to Magento 2 development. Only my 3rd week working with it .. do you mind explaining a bit more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in etc/area/di.xml update this things, it will work.

```
 <type name="\Magento\Framework\DB\Helper\Mysql\Fulltext">
    <plugin name="QuickSearch-plugin" type="Vendor\ExtendedQuickSearch\Plugin\QuickSearch" />
</type>
```

Comment: @AnandOntigeri worked like a charm thanks! Although you are missing a double quote after name=